# Typescript transformer, `node.parent` is undefined

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

I'm currently using a typescript transformer api, and I found that the `node.parent` is undefined.

My code is:

```
        const transformerFactory: ts.TransformerFactory<ts.Node> = (
            context: ts.TransformationContext
        ) => {
            return (rootNode) => {
                function visit(node: ts.Node): ts.Node {
                    node = ts.visitEachChild(node, visit, context);

                    // HERE node.parent IS UNDEFINED !

                    return filterFn(node, context);


                }
        
                return ts.visitNode(rootNode, visit);
            };
        };
        
        const transformationResult = ts.transform(
            sourceFile, [transformerFactory]
        );
```

How can I find the parent of the node?

Comment: The root node has no parent.

Comment: I don't get parent for every other node

Answer (score 5):

You can parse specifying to set the parent nodes:

```
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
    "fileName.ts",
    "class Test {}",
    ts.ScriptTarget.Latest,
    /* setParentNodes */ true, // specify this as true
);
```

Or do some operation on the node to get it to set its parent nodes (ex. type check the program... IIRC during binding it ensures the parent nodes are set).

**Update based on comment**

If you are creating these from a program, then you can do the following:

```
const options: ts.CompilerOptions = { allowJs: true };
const compilerHost = ts.createCompilerHost(options, /* setParentNodes */ true);
const program = ts.createProgram([this.filePath], options, compilerHost);
```

Comment: Is this possible if I have  `this.program = ts.createProgram([this.filePath], { 
            allowJs: true
        }); this.sourceFile = this.program.getSourceFile(this.filePath); ` ?

Comment: @nexis no problem!